# command/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1- code sign error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, codesign, xcode-archive

I'm currently in the process of submitting my first app to the Apple store.
I've completed the following processes

1. Obtained a developer account
2. Logged into the Member Center to Create an App ID
3. Used keychain access to request and receive a distribution certificate
4. Obtained a provisioning profile using my id and certificate

When I build the app it runs perfectly in the app simulator and on the actual ipad, however when I switch my app to `Archive` on iOS Device i have a major code sign error which i've attached below.

```
codesign /Users/Gaby/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RoyalAppInspection-dthvtpxadkslqmhkwdpaqkyujscg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RoyalAppInspection.app
cd /Users/Gaby/Desktop/RoyalAppInspection
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin


/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 79640A11C8D22589BD337496ABB8443581513846 --entitlements /Users/Gaby/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RoyalAppInspection-dthvtpxadkslqmhkwdpaqkyujscg/Build/Intermediates/RoyalAppInspection.build/Debug-iphoneos/RoyalAppInspection.build/RoyalAppInspection.app.xcent /Users/Gaby/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RoyalAppInspection-dthvtpxadkslqmhkwdpaqkyujscg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/RoyalAppInspection.app

79640A11C8D22589BD337496ABB8443581513846: no identity found Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I have no idea what to do to fix this, as I've tried to make sure all the other aspects of the process were completed correctly.

One concern i did have was when i clicked the provisioning profile file it would not open and "add to library" wouldn't pop up (i cannot access iphone configuration utility for some reason.) I manually added the .mobileprovision file to my xcode project but i'm thinking this may also be a source of my error.

Anyone, can you please help?

Comment: Have you added your account in `Xcode` -> `Preferences` -> `Accounts`?

Comment: Refer to the Apple answer, it worked for me:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1940/_index.html

Comment: @DatDaoVan after trying to solve this for two full days this is what finally made it work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You almost made it on your own, but in the end there seems to be something wrong with your profile.

First I would recommend a tool to "look inside" the profile to make sure it's the right one: http://furbo.org/2013/11/02/a-quick-look-plug-in-for-provisioning/

This will just add some more information about the profile, when selecting it in Finder and pressing space (Quick Look).

---

Check your **Xcode Preferences**:

1. Xcode Perferences (CMD + ,)
2. Accounts
3. Select your account on the left
4. Select view details on the bottom right
5. Refresh (using the small button on the bottom left)

[image: Xcode Settings]

Xcode stores the profiles in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`

**If your distribution profile is not in there, double click on it.**

*Then it should appear in that folder, but with a hashed name, e.g. `1edf8f42-fd1c-48a9-8938-754cdf6f7f41.mobileprovision`* at this point the Quick Look plugin comes in handy :-)

---

Next, check your **Project Settings**:

1. select the target (not project) you want to build in Xcode
2. switch to build settings
3. look for the "Code Signing" section
4. check if the correct profile is selected under "Provisioning Profile" => "Release"

[image: Build Settings]

---

Next, check your **Scheme Settings**:

1. select Product menu
2. open scheme submenu
3. select edit scheme...
4. select "Archive" on the left
5. Build configuration should be set to "Release"

[image: Scheme Settings]

---

Next, check the **Keychain Access** `Trust` settings:

1. open keychain access (spotlight => keychain)
2. select login
3. click on Certificates
4. look for `iPhone Distribution: Elena Carrasco (8HE2MJLM25)` on the right
5. right click, select "Get Info"
6. open "Trust" section
7. set to "Use System Defaults"
8. repeat steps 5 to 7 for `Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority`

[image: Keychain]

---

Next, check the **Keychain Access** private key `Access Control`:

1. repeat steps 1 to 4 from previous check
2. expand the profile to make your private key visible
3. right click on the private key, select "Get Info"
4. switch to "Access Control"
5. select "Confirm before allowing access"
6. use the "+" button to add "codesign" (normally located in `/usr/bin/codesign`) 
   *Hint: if it doesn't show up in the file browser, use `cmd + shift + g` to enter the path manually*
7. when using Carthage: add `/usr/bin/productbuild` here as well (thx to [DesignatedNerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681493))
8. "Save Changes"

[image: Keychain 2]

Hope one of this does trick for you!

---

**Update (4/22/16):**

I just found a very nice explanation about the whole code sign process (it's really worth reading):
https://www.objc.io/issues/17-security/inside-code-signing/

Comment: wow, this response is way beyond any help that i expected but props to d4Rk for an awesome awesome solution. Thank you so much I really appreciate it.

Comment: Problem fixed, now awaiting response from the apple store!

Comment: I don't know how pioneers like you figure this stuff out, d4rk. Apple Docs certainly don't make it easy. Thanks a million

Comment: I've gone through that mess way too many times.. And after spending just too much time with that, I started to put all this possible flaws together, as a tutorial / checklist for myself. And when I saw this question/problem here, I thought that would fit good as an answer.

Comment: How do I add /usr/bin/codesign to the keychain access when the file open dialog hides my /usr directory? I've tried running "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES" and it now shows /usr in the normal finder window, but still not in keychain access file open dialog.

Comment: Just use `cmd + shift + g` to enter the path manually. You can use this in any finder file browser window on the mac.

Comment: where is the `view details on the bottom right` on the accounts setting? I am using Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: @armnotstrong There were a lot of changes in Xcode and generally according to code signing in the past. So I may need to update the answer to work for newer Xcode versions as well (once I have some more time). 
But for now, I think the "refresh" button under "view details" is more or less the same as the "Download All Profiles" button now.

Comment: @d4Rk thanks for replaying have tried download all profile button，but got no luck ：(

Comment: @armnotstrong Did you try anything else or could you isolate the issue somehow at least? Hard to help you without anymore information. As you can see in my answer there are so many possible issues (and I guess my answer is far from complete).

Comment: @d4Rk hi，thanks for asking，turn to other project since I stuck there. the only thing I can remeber is that this happens after I drag a folder to the project and made it blue by made a reference to that，before that，things works fine，some other guy suggest make sort of 'attr' messing stuff about the image just imported，but none of that work either，it's late here and maybe I will dig into this tomorrow，and if any thing works，will let you know，sorry if any typo，texting on a mobile device now

Comment: Ran into this with team members who were having trouble having Carthage frameworks to sign and this answer was a huge help. For us we compared my signing setup (working) to theirs (not) and it turned out that I had granted access to `/usr/bin/productbuild` in addition to `/usr/bin/codesign` and Xcode. Definitely worth checking that if you're using Carthage for dependency management.

Comment: @d4Rk For me in the Access Control screen of private key Save changes is not working. When I try to close the window confirmation dialog pops up asking if I want to save the changes. These changes are not getting saved even if I click the save. Please help. This is urgent for me.

Comment: Worked a charm!!

Answer (score 106):

The following steps solved the problem for me. I was having the issue where it was not compiling for the device or archiving, working fine for simulator.

1. Open keychain access.
2. Lock the 'login' keychain.
3. Unlock it.

Clean and build after doing the above steps and everything works fine now.

Comment: Thanks, mate. Saved me a ton of headache.

Comment: i spent 3.00 Am to 7.39 Am finally it's resolved!!. i am like is that simple. amazing!!

Answer (score 35):

For me following steps worked:

1. Quit `Xcode`.
2. Open `Terminal`.
3. Typed Command `xattr -rc /Users/manabkumarmal/Desktop/Projects/MyProjectHome`
4. Open Xcode.
5. Cleaned.
6. Now worked and No Error.

Comment: In terms of what this does, per the [xattr man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html) it cleans extended attribute data from the  directory at the path passed as the final parameter, recursively. Why that helps, I've got no idea.

Answer (score 19):

This worked for me. Give it a try:

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
xattr -rc .
```

Comment: thanks @Shree. After run that comment on terminal you should RESTART your computer. Work for me like this.

Answer (score 10):

I had this error in Xcode 8 and Mac OS Sierra. Tried all the above solutions and none worked. This was the only one that worked for me. Open terminal, and type this in:

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
xattr -c *
```

Answer (score 4):

For me "Restarting Mac System" got worked

Answer (score 3):

For me, i just cleaned the app and it worked (cmd + shift + k), removing the error. I got the error after updating to swift 2.3.

Answer (score 3):

Another reason you may see this error that I haven't seen posted yet, especially if you are using Jenkins, is that your certificate's private key needs "Allow all applications to access this item" selected.

1. Open your Mac keychain
2. Go to "Certificates" or "My Certificates" under "Category" on the left.
3. Find the cert you're trying to sign with, and click the little grey triangle on the left of the certificate to reveal the associated private key.
4. Left/ double-click the private key and select "Get Info."
5. Toggle from "Attributes" to "Access control"
6. Select "Allow all applications to access this item" and save changes.
   [image]
   I maintain a large cluster of Mac mini nodes as part of a centralized Jenkins CI system, and this can come up.

Comment: This fixed my issue. So many things can go wrong in this process. Thanks

Comment: This helped me too... thanks for taking time and sharing it here.

Answer (score 2):

Do everything d4Rk suggests, that is a *great* walk-through.
if it still isn't signing, you might have some expired or revoked certificates. I find this can happen when you're working on a team.

1. quit xcode.
2. open Keychain Access.
3. in the 'Certificates' section, go through all "iPhone Distribution" certificates and if they're expired or revoked or otherwise invalid, delete them.
4. same as 3, but for the 'My Certificates' section.
5. re-open xcode and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Open the project into the Xcode.
Select `project.app` file and right click on it, select “show in finder” option.
Open terminal and go to the `project.app` file path.

Type the following to commands one by one:

```
xattr -lr project.app
xattr -cr project.app
```

Open the project and run.

Answer (score 2):

I Followed all the things mentioned in this thread but still facing same issue-

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign A7F8FCD694D7923A3E57826398C3380E2E5A5446 --entitlements  unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I have configured **Automatic signing** with my code base which will work with **xcode run** as well as **xcodebuild run  from terminal** from my machine but it gives above error when I run it on jenkins pipeline or try to run on terminal from remotely connected machine

In my case Automatic signing is not working if access remotely. because I need to open keychain before archive using

```
security unlock-keychain -p "newpassword" "/Users/xyz/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
```

keychain passwords & login password for macOS X user was different I change it to new same password and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem, very easily.

- Just reboot the computer ( it refreshes everything by itself ).

I hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

Reboot also worked for me. Interestingly it seems to be an issue with allowing Xcode access to the certificates. When i tried the archive again, i received 2 popups asking me if i wanted to allow Xcode to access my keychain. After this it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just reset your development and distribution certificate and clean your project.
After that ,
Reboot also worked for me. Interestingly it seems to be an issue with allowing Xcode access to the certificates. When i tried the archive again, i received 2 popups asking me if i wanted to allow Xcode to access my keychain. After this it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the existing precompiled files:

```
rm -rf  /Users/raghu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Solitare-fdaukpanamlzllacxvdzfbeqcrsg/
```

And try to build it again.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting didn't work for me.

Just try with downloading and adding the Certificate again to keyChain. That worked for me. When I checked Keychain Access the respective certificate was missing. Got the problem solve when I reinstalled the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

delete your certificate in your dev then Reinstall and it will working!

Answer (score 0):

I have Solved This Problem. If your project has .xcdatamodeld file (mean you are using coreData) then make sure the entities you formed go its Data Model Inspector and check Class has codegen, manual/None or classdefination. if it is class defination then make it manual/None and clean the project and run again. screenshots are given below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is working in @d4Rk solution Just use the below screen to delete unwanted/expired similar provision profiles. Right click on provision profile to move it to trash. 
[provision profile window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkbf1.png)

Because in my case after doing all the steps I was still getting the same issue and it resolved when I deleted old expired provision profiles with same name and then using the correct one in build setting.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, some pods were out of date after I updated my OS. Here's what fixed it:

In terminal:

```
cd /Users/quaisafzali/Desktop/AppFolder/Application/
pod install
```

Then, open your project in Xcode and Clean it (Cmd+Shift+K), then Build/Run.

This worked for me, hope it helps some of you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on January 2018 with xcode 8.2.1

Before I try to open xcode I couldn't because the system was updating. I tried sometime later and it let me working on it, and then I got the same error.

I followed most of the solutions described in this article but they didn't work for me.

Then I remembered the message about the system updating and I tried to reboot the machine.

And that did the magic. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting worked for me too. After upgrading to High Sierra I got tons of problems with password and it looks like I needed to enter the Password for the Keychain access to XCode.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue and all above solutions didn't work for me.

The reason why it works on your simulator but not real devices is probably related to your `Development Certificate`.

So I revoked my certificate on Apple Developer Portal and request a new one on my computer. Here are the steps:

1. Goto [Apple Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/development) and revoke your old (not working) development certificate. [image: revoke]
2. Add iOS App Development Certificate [image: add]
3. Follow the step on from Apple
4. Download the newly generated certificate and add it (double click) to your Keychain [image: download]
5. Make sure it is in your XCode Accounts [image: accounts]

Then it works!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the issue after select the deny when it asks for permission

After some search I got it fixed by restarting the system.

Answer (score 0):

Today, 2020 year, I've solved this problem with Xcode 11.7, Xcode 12.0 and Xcode 12.1 following these steps:

### Identifying the bad certificate:

- From you Keychains select Login
- From Category select Certificates
- Find any Apple Certificate that has the blue +
- Double click on the certificate.
- Expand the Trust

**If it's messed up then the "When using this certificate" is set to "Always Trust" along with the blue +**

### Fixing the bad certificate:

- **Just set it to "Use System Defaults" and close it.**
- You'll get a pop up. Type in your password to update settings.
- Close KeyChain.
- Go back to your project, clean and run.

Problem should have gone away.
If that didn't work then go back to Keychain and just double check and see if there are any other Apple certificates that are set to Always Trust and repeat the process.

Answer (score -2):

The easy way (which will do all png files) I used:

Run This Command in Terminal

```
find . -name "*.png" -exec xattr -c {} \;
```