# Alamofire error: Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 No such file or directory & umbrella header for Pods-Alamofire-umbrella.h

Tags: ios, alamofire

i'm trying to ***Archive*** my app according to Apple's "App Distribution Guide", app is operating fine both on simulator and iPhone, no errors found. But when i just click ***Archive***, two errors always happen:

**one says:** 
Swift Compiler Warning: Umbrella header for module 'Alamofire' does not include header 'Pods-Alamofire-umbrella.h'.

**second says:**
/Users/applejwo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cloud-eixkwmelyvsoqvabyduxipaohojy/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Cloud/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/Alamofire.framework: No such file or directory
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

*the second error sometimes may disappear, i also don't know why?*

i have tried every possible solution stated in "[command/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1- code sign error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242485/command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-code-sign-error#)", but errors are still there.

my dev environment is: simulator 8.4, iPhone 5s iOS 8.4, Xcode 6.4 (6E35b), swift, Alamofire 1.2.3, cocoa pods 0.37.2

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After days of looking on Github and stackoverflow, it seems the problem of cocoapods, pls see here [github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3200](http://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3200);

My solution is updating the cocoapods to 0.38.0.beta.2, But just not enough to me, as it reports errors again;

So i reinstalled my pods **Alamofire** and **swiftyJSON**.

Finally errors are fixed, project Achieved successfully! I don't know why, but hope the solution works for you, it's really depressing by stuck at the final step to AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

This is a blockheaded mistake to make, but in case anybody else is equally blockheaded: The Alamofire framework has two versions, one for iOS and one for OSX. From the [Alamofire doc](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire):

> Select the top Alamofire.framework for iOS and the bottom one for OS X.

Selecting the wrong one will let the project build correctly on the simulator, but will produce the `exit code 1` error when trying to archive.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting these two problems using Xcode 7 beta 2 and using Swift 2.0. I'm also using the `swift-2.0` branch of Alamofire.

I was able to get rid of the second error by revoking my certificate and creating a new one. I happen to have just transferred to a new Mac and I restored it from a Time Machine backup of my old work computer, so I *guessed* that the code signing errors came from that.

The first error, I still have and I have no idea how to fix it. Will update this answer when I do.

Comment: After days of looking on Github and stackoverflow, it may the problem of cocoapods, pls see here "https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3200". My solution is updated the cocoapods to 0.38.0.beta.2, and reinstalled my pods "Alamofire and swiftyJSON", seems errors fixed, and my project Achieved successfully.