# Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 Xcode CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, cocoapods

I've been trying to debug this error for hours, it says Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Seems to involve the code signing, and I've refreshed provisioning profiles, removed Derived Data, cleaned the project, and tried everything else on SO but nothing works. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the screenshot:

[image: Error Log]

Comment: Have you checked the [Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action)?

Comment: what am i looking for here? Expired profiles?

Comment: @mettymcgee Yeah just check everything if there's something suspicious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Check those link  i am sure you got your solution

[Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017756/command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)

[/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090288/usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)

[command/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1- code sign error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242485/command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-code-sign-error)

Comment: Nope that's the problem, I read all three of those and tried all of those steps, it seems related to CocoaPods which none of those are about.

Comment: This answer was accepted because of it was helpful to @mattgabor question to solve his problem.

Comment: why you are asking...?

Comment: Do you have a better suggestion @JMStudios.jrichardson?

Comment: having a similar issue where the error is shown for a few pods in my projects... how did you end up resolving this? @mattgabor

Comment: @nburk did you find a solution?