# Code signing issue

Tags: swift, xcode

I recently put my app in the App Store and that all went well.
But al the sudden I get this error:
I tried to fix for 2 days now but I can't get it working.

```
Signing Identity:     "-"

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp=none /Users/Camiel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Schoolcijfer-emiqdjjbklgtsubgztwtxcsxbhby/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Schoolcijfer.app

/Users/Camiel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Schoolcijfer-emiqdjjbklgtsubgztwtxcsxbhby/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Schoolcijfer.app: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I have updated to the latest xcode version 8.0, that maybe is the source of the problem. But i am not sure I also could have done something stupid.

I have tried many things from the following question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242485/command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-code-sign-error), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090288/usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1) and [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017756/command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)
But non of them have worked, could anyone please help?

Comment: See my answer for same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652867/code-sign-error-in-macos-sierra-xcode-8-resource-fork-finder-information-or/39667628#39667628

Comment: The answer from [Guru](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652867/code-sign-error-in-macos-sierra-xcode-8-resource-fork-finder-information-or/39667628#39667628) worked for me.